# Group by with join condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I've been asked to create a view with full outer join of two tabe departments and employees as the following question:

Create a new view name as fullview. Get the following column: MIN(LASTNAME) name as name, distinct (manager_id) rename as “Available Manager_id”, count (manager_id) rename as “No. of Manager_id”,  and the sum(salary) per job_id. Apply Full Outer Join

Since it's been asked to sum(salary) per job_id ,I think need to be used group by but I donot know how.I would very appreciate that somebody can help me and fix my following statement regarding the above question:

```
CREATE VIEW FULLVIEW
AS ( 
         SELECT MIN(LASTNAME) AS NAME,
                DISTINCT(E.MANAGER_ID) AS "Available Manager_id", 
                COUNT(E.MANAGER_ID) AS "No.of Manager_id",
                JOB_ID, 
                sum(salary)
           FROM EMPLOYEES E 
FULL OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D
             ON E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
       GROUP BY JOB_ID);
```

Comment: Please, attach db structure and mock data.

Comment: For departments table:  
department_id (not null) ,department_name(not null),manager_id,location_id

Comment: Also attach required output along with the inputs asked by @Maxim

Comment: For employees table:employee_id(not null),firstname,lastname(not null),job_id,salary,manager_id,department_id

Comment: NO required outpu is available just the above question that I got confused the last item sum(salary) per job_id and i got error over the above statement

Comment: Unrelated, but: the parentheses around the actual query are useless

Comment: @Steve . . . If you are going to write an accurate query, then *you* should be able to mock up data and product desired results.  How else will you know if a query is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible and correct answer that I found for the question is as following answer:

```
CREATE VIEW fullview
AS
   (  SELECT DISTINCT (d.manager_id) AS "Available Manager_id",
                      MIN (lastname) AS name,
                      COUNT (d.manager_id) AS "No.of Manager_id",
                      job_id,
                      SUM (salary) AS salary
        FROM employees e
             FULL OUTER JOIN departments d ON e.manager_id = d.manager_id
    GROUP BY e.job_id, d.manager_id);
```